# Make YouTube video embed responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, bootstrap-5

I have some videos that are embedded on my webpage from YouTube. The thing is I am using the below-attached code to make it responsive (via bootstrap). It's good on mobile and tablets but on desktops and laptops is coming out to be very huge. When I could not solve the problem then I did not use YouTube embed and switched to the HTML5 video tag. In that, the responsive problem was solved by width:100% and height auto but the videos were not loading and kept on buffering. So, I again switched to YouTube embed so that at least the video loads but it's not really responsive (not on laptops, desktops). Also attaching the link for the webpage where the videos are embedded.

Code-

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kq7CdSf7ocA?rel=0" title="YouTube video 
      player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
      encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Comment: The version of bootstrap that I am using is 5.0.1

Comment: How big do you want it on desktop?

Comment: Its width should be approx. 900 and height auto.

Answer (score 3):

Remove inline style (`width` & `height`) from `iframe` element
then add this css code to you style file:

```
.container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
 }


iframe {
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting a `max-width` on the iframe.

-- Video not loading in snippet ... [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/y6su9415/5/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

iframe {
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="container">
  <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
     <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kq7CdSf7ocA?rel=0" title="YouTube video 
      player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
      encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I would like to ask you if the height can also be adjusted?

Comment: @YADAVMAHIR Yes, because there is no height set, it is using `height: 100%;` from `ratio`. So it's displaying a 900px height or as you said, `height: auto;`. See the adjustment, I made it so the max-height was 400px. (cut in half).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The problem has been resolved.

Comment: @YADAVMAHIR May I ask why the answer was unaccepted?